# How to split not well-formed xml files at the xml declaration tag to write it in seperate xml files to parse them?

Tags: java, mysql, xml, parsing, split

My Problem: I would like to parse a huge amount of large xml files and write the data in mysql database. The thing is, all of those xml files are not well-formed, since the authority merge multiple xml files in one xml file and publishes them.
So my SAX Parser with works perfectly for single xml files throws an error, he cannot handle a xml file, which contains multiple xml declarations (xml-version ...)

The thrown error message:

> Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId:
>   ..... "[xX][mM][lL]"  .....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE us-patent-grant SYSTEM "us-patent-grant-v42-2006-08-23.dtd" [ ]>
<us-patent-grant lang="EN" dtd-version="v4.2 2006-08-23" file="USD0535456-20070123.XML" status="PRODUCTION" id="us-patent-grant" country="US" date-produced="20070110" date-publ="20070123">
<us-bibliographic-data-grant>
<publication-reference>
<document-id>
<country>US</country>
<doc-number>D0535456</doc-number>
<kind>S1</kind>
<date>20070123</date>
</document-id>
</publication-reference>
<us-application-series-code>29</us-application-series-code>
</us-bibliographic-data-grant>
</us-patent-grant>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE us-patent-grant SYSTEM "us-patent-grant-v42-2006-08-23.dtd" [ ]>
<us-patent-grant lang="EN" dtd-version="v4.2 2006-08-23" file="USD0535457-20070123.XML" status="PRODUCTION" id="us-patent-grant" country="US" date-produced="20070110" date-publ="20070123">
<us-bibliographic-data-grant>
...
```

Since I was looking into several forums and websites the only sober solution is to read the xml file split it at the root tag and write it in seperate xml files? How can I read and write a xml file without parsing it with SAX / Stax / DOM?

Results should be: 
XML FILE 1:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE us-patent-grant SYSTEM "us-patent-grant-v42-2006-08-23.dtd" [ ]>
<us-patent-grant lang="EN" dtd-version="v4.2 2006-08-23" file="USD0535456-20070123.XML" status="PRODUCTION" id="us-patent-grant" country="US" date-produced="20070110" date-publ="20070123">
<us-bibliographic-data-grant>
...
</us-bibliographic-data-grant>
</us-patent-grant>
```

XML FILE 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE us-patent-grant SYSTEM "us-patent-grant-v42-2006-08-23.dtd" [ ]>
<us-patent-grant lang="EN" dtd-version="v4.2 2006-08-23" file="USD0535457-20070123.XML" status="PRODUCTION" id="us-patent-grant" country="US" date-produced="20070110" date-publ="20070123">
<us-bibliographic-data-grant>
...
```

Comment: have you tried:https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm ?

Comment: Yes, I tried. The DocumentBuilder also uses the parsing function, which runs into the error - xml files with multiple xml declarations cannot be parsed, cause they aren't well-formed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your file has multiple xml documents in it, it's not really an xml file. It's just a file. So you could read it with anything you like to read files with (e.g. a FileReader).

Another option would be to extend a reader or stream and create a new class which handles files with multiple xml documents. It would need to :

- Return an end of file when a new xml document is found, this would tell the parser it's done with the current document
- Allow reading to continue after the pseudo end of file so the next xml doc can be read
- Handle close so that it's only closed when the whole file is read, might also want some sort of force close option

Something along the lines of...

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;

public class ConcatenatedXmlReader extends BufferedReader {

    private String nextLine = "";

    public ConcatenatedXmlReader(Reader reader, int size) {
        super(reader, size);
    }

    public ConcatenatedXmlReader(Reader reader) {
        super(reader);
    }

    private boolean seenXmlStart = false;

    // which method you need to override probably depends on which sax parser you use
    @Override
    public int read(char[] buffer, int offset, int length) throws IOException {
        readNextLine();
        if (nextLine == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (nextLine.startsWith("<?xml")) {
            if (seenXmlStart) {
                return -1;
            }
            seenXmlStart = true;
        }
        int addToBuffer = Math.min(nextLine.length(), length);
        for (int i = 0; i < addToBuffer; i++) {
            buffer[i] = nextLine.charAt(i);
        }
        nextLine = (addToBuffer < nextLine.length()) ? nextLine.substring(addToBuffer) : "";
        return addToBuffer;
    }

    public boolean hasXmlDocuments() throws IOException {
        readNextLine();
        seenXmlStart = false;
        return nextLine != null &&  nextLine.length() > 0;
    }

    private void readNextLine() throws IOException {
        if (nextLine != null && nextLine.length() == 0) {
            nextLine = readLine();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        // override so it doesn't close the file when there are still more xml documents.
        if (nextLine != null) {
            return;
        }
        super.close();
    }

}
```

You'd then call the sax parser multiple times while there were more xml docs in the file.

e.g.

```
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        MyHandler handler = new MyHandler();
        ConcatenatedXmlReader reader = new ConcatenatedXmlReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
        while (reader.hasXmlDocuments()) {
            saxParser.parse(new InputSource(reader), handler);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for!